# Splitting a string into characters, but keeping some together

Tags: c#, string, split

I have this string: `TF'E'`

I want to split it to characters, but the  `'`" character should join the character before it.

So it would look like this: `T`, `F'` and `E'`

Comment: Just split on `'`, then for each split on char, then if needed add the `'` back to the last of each group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to split the string at each position immediately before a new letter and an optional `'`:

```
var input = "TF'E'";
var output = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<!^)(?=\p{L}'?)");
```

`output` will now be a string array like `["T", "F'", "E'"]`. The lookbehind `(?<!^)` ensure we never split at the start of the string, whereas the lookahead `(?=\p{L}'?)` describes one letter `\p{L}` followed by 0 or 1 `'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to capture "an uppercase character followed optionally by an apostrophe"

```
var mc = Regex.Matches(input, "(?<x>[A-Z]'?)");

foreach(Match m in mc)
  Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["x"].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like regex, you can use this method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Split(string input)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if(i != (input.Length - 1) && input[i+1] == '\'')
            {
                yield return input[i].ToString() + input[i+1].ToString();
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
            yield return input[i].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

We loop through the input string. We check if there is a next character and if it is a '. If true, return the current character and the next character and increase the index by one. If false, just return the current character.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sPCftB